# xamarin ios c# underline UIButton text

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, uibutton

I am trying to underline the text in this `UIButton` **("Privacy Policy")**. How can this be accomplished? Here is my code:

```
var PrivacyPolicy = new UIButton(new CGRect(10, s.MxHt - 40, (s.MxWd - 20) / 3, 30));

PrivacyPolicy.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 92, 191);
PrivacyPolicy.Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto", 14f);
PrivacyPolicy.SetTitle("Privacy Policy", UIControlState.Normal);
PrivacyPolicy.TouchUpInside += HandleBtnOpenPrivacyTouchUpInside;            

if (iPad == false)
{
    PrivacyPolicy.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12);
}

View.AddSubview(PrivacyPolicy);
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, I found this to work as well. Thank you!

```
        //Set attribute for underlineing information links
        var underlineAttr = new UIStringAttributes { UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single, ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };

        //Privacy Button Link
        var PrivacyPolicy = new UIButton(new CGRect(10, s.MxHt - 40, (s.MxWd - 20) / 3, 30));
        PrivacyPolicy.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 92, 191);
        PrivacyPolicy.Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto", 14f);            
        PrivacyPolicy.SetAttributedTitle(new NSAttributedString("Privacy Policy", underlineAttr), UIControlState.Normal);
        PrivacyPolicy.TouchUpInside += HandleBtnOpenPrivacyTouchUpInside;            
        if (iPad == false) { PrivacyPolicy.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12); }            
        View.AddSubview(PrivacyPolicy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set attibuted title on button like this

```
let attStr : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Privacy Policy")
        attStr.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attStr.length))


PrivacyPolicy.setAttributedTitle(attStr, forState: .Normal)
```

And you can't create button using new keyword or you created in that way in swift, So please use like this

```
var PrivacyPolicy = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x: 10,  y: 40, width: 50 , height: 30));
```

Comment: Mukesh the question asks about C# solution, it's for Xamarin, not with Swift.

Comment: @DenninDalke oh its about xamarin, don't know too much about xamarin